# RequireJS / BackboneJS app - Need suggestion on adding dependency

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I am developing an app using backboneJS/requireJS. I have identified around 20 views, and for all the views I am using jquery, backbonejs and underscorejs. So my first three dependencies are always these three.

```
define([
  'jquery', 
  'underscore', 
  'backbone',
 .... ], function($, _, Backbone, ..){
.....

});
```

Is there a way i can skip and say somewhere at global level to include these three in all modules, so that I can avoid writing them redundantly in all files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. One is to wrap `define` in your own `myDefine` (or whatever):

```
myDefine = function(dependencies, callback) {
  var defaults = ['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'],
      combined = defaults.concat(dependencies);

  return define(combined, callback);
};

myDefine(['MyView'], function($, _, Backbone, MyView) {
  // do stuff
});
```

But this obviously still requires you to specify the objects in your callback. So a better option might be to attach `$`, `_`, and `Backbone` to your application namespace (if you don't want them to be global). Then you could do something like this:

```
myDefine = function(dependencies, callback) {
  var defaults = ['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'];

  if (myApp.$ && myApp._ && myApp.Backbone) {
    define(dependencies, callback);
  } else {
    require(defaults, function($, _, Backbone) {
      myApp.$ = $;
      myApp._ = _;
      myApp.Backbone = Backbone;
      define(dependencies, callback);
    }
  }
};

myDefine(['MyView'], function(MyView) {
  // use myApp.$, myApp._, myApp.Backbone
});
```

If you don't care about namespacing, you could just do the above without the `myApp` steps and let the libs stay in `window`.

Note that all above is untested.

The simpler option of course is simply to load jQuery, Underscore, and Backbone synchronously before any of your modules.

Comment: Thanks Glortho! I would follow the second suggestion.